# Pandas DataReader produces DataFrame with inaccessible indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I'm pulling data from pandas.datareader and cannot access the data by index. Here's the code to produce the dataframe with a single, date-indexed row:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
tdata = data.DataReader('SPY', 'iex', '2018-03-23', '2018-03-23')
```

Now, `print(tdata)` returns the data as expected:

```
            open    high     low   close     volume
date                                                 
2018-03-23  264.17  265.02  257.83  258.05  183534751
```

I can print the index value with `print(tdata.index.values)`, resulting in: `['2018-03-23']`

However, `print(tdata['2018-03-23'])` returns `KeyError`

Trying to access the index directly through a loop also results in `KeyError`

```
for idx in tdata.index.values:
    print(tdata[idx])
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing as `df[id]`, pandas decides what's inside the `[]` as follows:

- String - Gets columns matching the value
- Int - Gets row with this index, if the index is of int type.
- Range of index values - Gets a subset of rows with that index

As you have a non-int type index, try `tdata.loc['2018-03-23']` as this will make pandas interpret the string as index value.